# I want to calculate $\int f(X_t) dB_t$ where $B(t)$ is Brownian motion and $X_t$ satisfies $d X_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

Let $B_t$ be Brownian motion, and $X_t$ satisfies the following Ito SDE:
$$
d X_t = \mu\, dt + \sigma\, d B_t,
$$
and $f$ is a function over $X_T$. I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)dB_t]$.

---

It seems that the result is $\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)dB_t] = 0$, but I fail to prove it. I know the following equations hold
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_t] = 0, \quad \mathbb{E}[dB_t] = 0.
$$
However, since there is an additional term, i.e., $f(X_t)$ in the expectation, $\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)dB_t] = f(X_t)\mathbb{E}[dB_t] = f(X_t) * 0 = 0 $ doesn't hold. Could anyone tell me how to prove it?

Comment: It seems that this question is related to this answer: [Itō Integral has expectation zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232932/it%C5%8D-integral-has-expectation-zero)

Comment: I think your phrasing is off. What does $dB_t$ even mean outside the context of an SDE? Perhaps you mean $\mathbb{E}[df(X_t)dB_t]$?